# Hypothesis testing with an (maybe) unfair coin with probability of head $p$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Given a (maybe) unfair coin with probability of head $p$, which is a realization of uniform RV $\underline{p}$ over [0, 1], and given we have N flips. We have 2 hypotheses:

\begin{align}
H_0: \underline{p} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\\
H_1: \underline{p} > \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Then how can we find a decision rule that has minimum probability of error? I think in case of $p_0$ of $H_0$ and $p_1$ of $H_1$ are unknown, we can decide a Critical Value (CV) unpon minimizing:

\begin{align}
P_e=\int_{0}^{CV} {N \choose k}(p_1)^k(1-p_1)^{N-k} \,dp_1 + \int_{CV}^{N} {N \choose k}(p_0)^k(1-p_0)^{N-k} \,dp_2
\end{align}
however I don't know how to apply to the case here.